# What is the difference between firebase_core and firebase_core_web packages for Flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, dart-packages

I want to create a Flutter web project. I see two packages listed on the package page. What is the difference between the two?
[firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) and [firebase_core_web](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core_web)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`firebase_core_web` is a part of `firebase_core`, check the dependencies in the [pubspec.yaml of source code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/pubspec.yaml). If you add `firebase_core` to your dependencies, it will include `firebase_core_web` as well. But you have to add different scripts to your `index.html` as well for Firebase to work on web.